# WSO2 ei 6.6.0 - activemq close session

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using WSO2 EI 6.6.0 with ActiveMQ 5.16.4 in the default configuration according to https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Configure+with+ActiveMQ+

Sometimes I encounter this error, which disconnects WSO2 from a specific queue. Restarting WSO2 is required to get everything working again. However, I'm unable to replicate this issue. Can you please advise?

```
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} - Error creating a JMS message from the message context javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating a JMS message from the message context
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory} - Error looking up the JMS destination with name my_queue of type queue javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory not found]
```

thank you